# Major performance issues with NVidia GT650M (standalone) 13.04 / 13.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, compiz, 13.10

I have a laptop (Lenovo y500) featuring a standalone/single Nvidia GeForce GT650m. Not a hybrid "optimus" configuration paired with the Intel HD graphics. I've tried basically all drivers from 304xx -> 331.13 beta drivers, and haven't seen any major performance changes. I've actually received far better Compiz performance using the Nouveau driver, however the Nouveau driver causes suspend issues with my machine.

While using the NVidia drivers, I can make tweaks using CompizConfig to gain some performance, but its still not comparable to the Nouveau drivers. Window movements are uncomfortably choppy... I've experimented with "Sync on VBlank" settings, FrameBuffer settings (which speeds things up, but causes significant tearing), etc.

Anyone have any other ideas?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.10. (I also had the same issues in 13.04)

Here is output from "lspci | grep VGA":

```
pmarino@olympus:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (reva1)
pmarino@olympus:~$
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I would stick with Nouveaux drivers and bare with the suspend issues (or try to fix them).

Comment: I've been switching back to the Nouveau drivers, however, in addition to the suspend issues... from time to time I rely on a second display, and the nouveau drivers have been having some issues with my HDMI out from the 650m, which is resolved by using  the Nvidia drivers. I guess i'll have to weigh out what is more important! :)